# What happens to a PN junction diode and its depletion width if forward bias voltage is greater than built-in voltage?

Tags: semiconductors, pn-junction

If the forward bias voltage applied to a PN junction diode is greater than the built-in voltage, what will happen? Will there be any depletion region? If a depletion region is still there, what will be its width? What will be the band diagram of the system? Please suggest some resources where I can find a mathematical treatment to this problem.
Thank you!!

Comment: I think this question has been answered already very, very often in relevant textbooks and/or internet contributions.

Comment: Can you suggest such textbook or website? I am surfing the internet now but can't find to-the-point answers.

Comment: @M. Fahmin. just look up semiconductor diodes on Wikipedia for a general treatment, then for more details, in any reputable texts on semiconductor physics...